# Dark mode detection in Node/Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I read on the electron's guide to [implement dark mode](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/dark-mode) to your app, but it only works when the user clicks a button to manually change it to dark mode. What I want to do is, when the system is in 'dark mode', I wanted the CSS tag to change. For instance, when a user has Dark Mode turned on in the system, it'll change the css background color to black.

here's the HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
```

Here's the javascript in the `renderer.js` file I used from [this site](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-detect-dark-mode/) with jQuery. I also had to use the `console.log` module to test to make sure the trigger works.

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
      .addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.matches) {

    //dark mode
$("nav.navbar-light bg-light").replaceWith( "navbar-light bg-dark" );
console.log("This is Dark Mode");

  } else {

    //light mode
$("nav.navbar-light bg-light").replaceWith( "navbar-light bg-light" );
console.log("This is Light Mode");

  }
})
```

I tried those, and nothing showed up on my console on launch. I know there has to be a different `window.NAMEOFTHING` in Electron/Node.js. I guess there's another npm I should try?

Comment: "*electron's guide to implement dark mode only works when the user clicks a button to manually change it to dark mode*" - uh, no? It explains also well how to use the system default instead of a manual toggle.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if system is in dark mode or not using the `nativeTheme` module.

So add this to your code:

```js
const electron = require("electron")
const nativeTheme = electron.remote.nativeTheme

if (nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors) {
    // Code here
}
```

However this only seems to work in compiled apps, so when I run `npm start` it does not work. It will return undefined, so for development you might wanna have a seperate function which checks if its undefined and defaults to dark or light mode.

Comment: What's a good function for it? Do you know by any chance? Couldn't I just use a `eventListener`?

Comment: You can detect if its undefined by using a if statement and default the value to true, and make it that it will be in dark mode or light mode accordingly

Comment: So just like the code you mentioned above, just append with the `== true { //action `?